# Can I apply Newton's equations of motion to relative motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, inertial-frames, relative-motion

We know that

Velocity of A relative to B is
$$ \vec v_{A|B} = \vec v_A - \vec v_B $$
and Acceleration of A relative to B is
$$ \vec a_{A|B} = \vec a_A - \vec a_B $$
So, is it correct to do this to find the displacement of A relative to B?:-

$$ \vec S_{A|B} = (\vec u_A - \vec u_B) t + 0.5 (\vec a_A - \vec a_B) t^2 $$

Comment: Note that ALL motion is relative.  When you define your velocity, you must measure that velocity with respect to some other object (e.g., a road surface, another vehicle, etc.).

Comment: both acceleration must be constant for the displacement formula to be applicable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes $$\vec S_A = \vec u_A t + 0.5 \vec a_A t^2$$ $$\vec S_B = \vec u_B t + 0.5 \vec a_B t^2$$ so then $$\vec S_{A|B}=\vec S_A - \vec S_B$$ recovers your expression.

Answer (score 0):

don't forget to specify three things:

1. the velocity you mentioned is initial velocity, so better to call them $v_{A0}$ and $v_{B0}$
2. this is true only for constant acceleration, otherwise we have to consider the function that describes it
3. A and B begin to accelerate at the same time respect to $t_0$.

Stated that, if acceleration is not constant but is a function of $t$ or even $s$ you have to integer them separately, and you lost the incisiveness of the formula you wrote